# How to Safely Update the ATi Propietary Drivers?

Tags: 10.10, drivers, ati, updates

I'm Currently using the ATi Drivers Supplied by Ubuntu, but i want to install the newest drivers ATI Released, i had a bad experience updating the drivers by just downloading them and runing the file, is there a safe way to install new drivers?

Also, i added the XUpdates PPA, does this PPA updates my drivers automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [X-Swat PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates). The AMD drivers here are currently a version behind those released by AMD (they are based on Catalyst 10.11 rather than 10.12) but work perfectly well and of course install (and update) without any issues.

If you want the latest Catalyst version then the AMD installer is very good unless you use an unsupported kernel; AMD do not yet officially support kernel versions greater than 2.6.35. Assuming you are using Ubuntu 10.10 with 2.6.25 you will have no issues.

Otherwise, look at my thread here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1615594. This gives details on patching Catalyst 10.12 for use on kernel versions 2.6.36 and 2.6.37.

Comment: AMD installer does indeed install the fglrx driver but it's a pain if you need to remove it again.

Comment: The AMD installer creates and installs .debs that can be removed (or downgraded) using synaptic. It is much better than it used to be.